# vb.net - add object to arraylist

Tags: vb.net, arrays, object, arraylist

I'm having some trouble adding an object to an arraylist.

Basically the object has two properties (file id/name), but I can't figure out how to assign those properties. During runtime it errors out with public member on the object not found.

```
Private QueueList As New ArrayList
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer)
    Dim QueueObj As New Object
    QueueObj.FileID = "Test 1"
    QueueObj.FileName = "Test 2"
    QueueList.Add(QueueObj)
End Sub
```

I'd also like to know how I can do a loop on the arraylist and access the two properites on each record.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you using arraylist?? Use list for this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just use "Object" for this. You need to build your own class:

```
Public Class File
    Public Property FileID As Integer
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Sub New ()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer)
        Me.FileID = FileID
        Me.FileName = FileName
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then build your Queue like this:

```
Private QueueList As New ArrayList()
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer)
    QueueList.Add(New File(FileName, FileID))
End Sub
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileObj As File)
    QueueList.Add(FileObj)
End Sub
```

Or, even better, use generics:

```
Public QueueList As New List(Of File)()
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer)
    QueueList.Add(New File(FileName, FileID))
End Sub
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileObj As File)
    QueueList.Add(FileObj)
End Sub
```

Then, to loop over list:

```
For Each item As File In QueueList
    'Console.WriteLine(item.FileID & vbTab & item.FileName)
Next item
```

Comment: With Option Strict Off in VB 10, you can just use Object and use the dynamic features added in .Net 4.

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to an object to hold your file information, and drop ArrayList for a strongly typed collection.

```
public class QueueFile
    public Property FileID as integer
    public property FileName as string
end class
```

...

```
Private QueueList As New List(Of QueueFile)
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer)
    Dim QueueObj As New QueueFile
    QueueObj.FileID = "Test 1"
    QueueObj.FileName = "Test 2"
    QueueList.Add(QueueObj)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two values, you may find using a generic Dictionary even better than an ArrayList (requiring boxing and unboxing the types) or List(Of T) which retains type safety.

```
Private QueueList As New Dictionary(of Integer, String)
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer)
   QueueList.Add(FileID, FileName)
End Sub
```

If you really want a Queue as your method name indicates, consider using the generic Queue. Also, if you only need a key/value pair, you don't need to create your own class. You can use the generic KeyValuePair(Of T, S):

```
Private QueueItems As New Queue(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
Public Sub Queue(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FileID As Integer)
   QueueItems.Enqueue(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(FileID, FileName))
End Sub
```

To get items out, use the QueueItems.Dequeue.